# How to quickly move items in the row of the matrix

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix

What am I doing?

1. Collect elements of the row to the array
2. Move them

How do I do this normally and quickly without collecting elements of row on array?

For example, I have a matrix:

```
static void initRow(int[] array, Cannon[, ] cn, int i, int size) {
  for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
    cn[i, j].A = array[j];
  }
}


static void ShiftLeftForK(int[] arr, int k) {
  for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
    ShiftLeft(arr);
  }
}

static void moveForB(Cannon[,] cn, int size) {
  int[] temp = new int[size];
  for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
      temp[j] = cn[j, i].B;
    }
    ShiftLeftForK(temp, i);
    initColumn(temp, cn, i, size);
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try a list instead of an array?  Lists are newer than array (carry over from legacy c) and uses references instead of value.

Comment: @jdweng: ??? I do not see in what a list is of any help here, since the matrix and the array most probably have a fixed size. Also, arrays are a fundamental concept in .NET and are first class objects in C#, i.e., C# has an array-specific syntax for arrays, while `List<T>` is an ordinary library class. Collections initializers are available for lists, but they are not `List<T>` specific, they apply to (almost) all collections. Whether lists are newer or not is irrelevant. Also, lists are always one-dimensional. Use lists when you need list semantics.

Comment: @jdweng You can't set the size of a list in advance like a regular array. The Add method doesn't work for me.

Comment: You do not need to preset size with a List.  You do need to call the constructor "new List<int>().

Comment: @jdweng But constructor initializes capacity, no size

Comment: @jdweng: When you do not specify an initial capacity, `List<T>` might resize its internal array often when you are adding many items. When you know the (approximate) number of items in advance, specifying the capacity reduces the number of array creations and array copy operations.

Comment: @QRUSH : where did you ever learnthat a constructor set size?  It depends on the type of class.  Most just call the default Net class constructor (base) and then added intialization of properties.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes : What is wrong with a class having the capability of adding and deleting data.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that. I was NOT talking about the capacity of doing something. By "capacity" I am speaking of the size of the internal array used by `List<T>`. You said *"You do need to call the constructor `new List<int>()`"*, but this does not specify the initial capacity. I said that it is better to use `new List<int>(initialCapacity)` if you know in advance how many items will be added to the list, because this avoids superfluous and costly array resize operations.